# Prove that the set of finite sets with bounded cardinal is closed with the hausdorff topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a normed vector space. $H$ is defined as the set of closed, bounded and non empty sets of $E$. for $A$ and $B$ in $H$ we define:
$$\phi(A,B)=\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)$$

and the distance between $A$ and $B$ is
$$h(A,B)=\max(\phi(A,B) ,\phi(B,A))$$

Let $s$ be an integer and   $H_s$ the subset of $H$ such that for all $A$ in $H_s$, $A$ is a finite set with a cardinal number in $\{1..s\}$

I have to prove that $H_s$ is a closed subset of H.

So I took a sequence $(A_n$) of $H_s$ such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}A_n=A  \in H$   and I want to prove that A is finite withe cardinal number in $\{1..s\}$
The idea I had was to write $A_n=\{a_n^1,..,a_n^s\}$ and prove that for all $a\in A$, $a$ is a limit of a sequence ($a_n^i$) . I tried manipulating the limits $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\phi(A_n,A)=0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\phi(A,A_n)=0$ but i'm still stuck.

Comment: Seems like it's probably easier to show that if $A \in H$ has at least $s+1$ distinct elements, then there's an $H$-open neighborhood around $A$ that is disjoint from $H_s$.  You can probably find that neighborhood by choosing an $\varepsilon$ that's small compared to the minimum distance between points of $A$.

Comment: It's easier if you're allowed to use that the Hausdorff metric induces the Vietoris hyperspace topology in this case. Then it's basically trivial.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm not sure of your point, perhaps because I've never heard of the Vietoris hyperspace topology.  Is there something wrong with my proof below?

Comment: @RobertShore I wasn’t suggesting there was, it’s just that I prefer the Vietoris topology for hyperspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $A \in H \setminus H_s$.  Then $A$ has at least $s+1$ distinct points, $\{ a_1, \ldots, a_{s+1} \}$.  Let $d$ be the minimum distance between any two of these points and let $\varepsilon = \frac d3 \gt 0$.  Then the triangle inequality tells us the $\varepsilon$-balls $B_i=B(a_i, \varepsilon) \subseteq E$ are mutually disjoint.

Choose $K \in H_s$.  Then because the $B_i$ are mutually disjoint, no point of $K$ can be in more than one $B_i$ so by the pigeonhole principle, for some $i, K \cap B_i = \varnothing$.  This shows that $\forall K \in H_s ~(h(K, A) \geq \phi(A, K) \geq d(a_i, K) \gt \varepsilon)$; in other words, $\{ B \in H \mid h(A, B) \lt \varepsilon \} \cap H_s = \varnothing$, or  $\{ B \in H \mid h(A, B) \lt \varepsilon \} \subseteq H \setminus H_s$.

This shows that $A$ is in the interior of $H \setminus H_s$. But $A$ was an arbitrary element of $H \setminus H_s$, so $H \setminus H_s \subseteq H$ is open and $H_s \subseteq H$ is closed.